# BLS API data using cURL and requests library?

Tags: python, python-requests

All, I'm trying to implement a curl request to get data from the BLS. Following their example [here](http://www.bls.gov/developers/api_unix.htm) (they show the curl request), my code looks like this:

```
import requests
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
params = {"seriesid":["LEU0254555900", "APU0000701111"],"startyear":"2002", "endyear":"2012"}
p = requests.post('http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/', params = params,headers = headers)
print p.url
print p.content
```

I'm getting the following (error) output:

> http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/?seriesid=LEU0254555900&seriesid=APU0000701111&endyear=2012&startyear=2002
>
> {"status":"REQUEST_FAILED","responseTime":0,"message":["Sorry, an
> internal error occurred.  Please check your input parameters and try
> your request again."],"Results":null}

Anyone had to deal with the BLS api and python?
Is the requests library the best for this?

Comment: As a side note: You want `'Content-Type'`, not `'Content-type'`. HTTP headers are [defined to be case-insensitive](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2), and most servers will handle them properly… but there are some poorly-written servers out there, and even more proxies, log parsers, etc. that get it wrong. So it's generally better to use the canonical capitalization—or, in your case, the same capitalization as the sample you're porting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send the data as json, not pass it as a `params` dict. `params` sets the url parameters, which is not what you want, you need to pass it as `data`.

This should work:

```
import requests
import json
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
data = json.dumps({"seriesid":["LEU0254555900", "APU0000701111"],"startyear":"2002", "endyear":"2012"})
p = requests.post('http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/', data=data, headers=headers)
print p.url
print p.content
```

Comment: In a POST, `params` may be sent as url-form-encoded post data instead of on the URL query string… but either way, it definitely won't magically figure out that you want JSON-encoded data instead of form-encoded and send it that way, and this is definitely the right answer.

Comment: @abarnert - may I ask how you come to that conclusion? The [docs](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.request) explicitly state that `params` will be sent in the query string.

Comment: By writing and debugging a project using `requests`. Considering that the project was written before even 1.0, much less 1.2, it's definitely plausible (maybe even likely) that things have changed and you now have more direct control. (But anyway, the main point is that no library can magically figure out that you want JSON-encoding in a general POST-sending method, so your answer is pretty much guaranteed to be right for any general-purpose HTTP library.)

Comment: @abarnert `params` is always the query string. Special magic is done to `data` during a POST if it's a dictionary, but that makes it form-encoded, not JSON.

Comment: @Lukasa: "… but that makes it form-encoded, not JSON" is my whole point.

Comment: @abarnert: Sorry, I wasn't disagreeing, I just wanted to be really emphatic about the behaviour of `params`. =)